# mysql で定期観測したデータから、変更があったレコードのみ選択したい

Tags: mysql, sql

例えば、スタックオーバーフローの自分の信用度を定時観測していたとします。(今回やりたいことは、たぶん stackexchange の api たたけば取得できそうですが、具体例として聞きたいので、 mysql の中で完結するような方法を探しています。)

そうすると、たとえば

```
observed_at,reputation
2017-11-1,1000
2017-11-2,1000
2017-11-3,1010
2017-11-4,1010
2017-11-5,1010
2017-11-6,1045
2017-11-7,1045
2017-11-8,1045
```

のようなデータが select できます。

この中から、 reputation に変化のあった最初のレコードたちを select したいと思いました。

```
observed_at,reputation
2017-11-1,1000
2017-11-3,1010
2017-11-6,1045
```

#### 質問

- mysql で、観測日時・その値のレコード列があったときに、データ値が変化した最初の観測だけを select するようにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

#### 追記

- 日付に漏れは、あっても対応できた方がうれしいです。何かしらの理由で定時観測が失敗する可能性があるので。。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68509/discussion-between-yuki-inoue-and-metropolis)しましょう。

Comment: ^ 「 長時間におよぶディスカッションをコメントで行うことは避けてください。自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか?」で OK 押すとこうなるっぽいですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的には、@suzukisさんのおっしゃる通り、プログラムでやるか、Postgresqlのような分析関数のあるDBでやるほうが素直かと思いますが、強引にやるとするなら、ユーザー変数を使ってrowidを採番すればできると思います。（２ステートメントになりますが・・・）

```
set @rowid_l = 0, @rowid_r = 0;

select l.observed_at, l.reputation
from    (
    select *, @rowid_l := @rowid_l + 1 as rowid from Test order by observed_at
) as l
left join (
    select *, @rowid_r := @rowid_r + 1 as rowid from Test order by observed_at
) as r
on l.rowid = r.rowid + 1
where r.rowid is null
    or l.reputation != r.reputation
order by l.rowid
;
```

Answer (score 1):

日付が連続しているという前提であれば、

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.observed_at - t2.observed_at,reputation WHERE t1.observed_at != t2.observed_at
```

こんな感じで、日付-1した自分自身とJOINして検索すればで解決出来ます。

日付が連続していないと、各行ごとに「1つ前の行」を検索で見つけてあげる必要があります。ウィンドウ関数をサポートしていれば簡単なのですが、MySQLはサポートしてないので、相関サブクエリで代替することになります。具体的に動くSQL提示できないので、「MySQL LAG」で検索すると解説が見つかります。

私ならややこしいSQLを保守するぐらいであれば

- プログラムで全件取得して処理する
- 日付が連続するよう補完する
- PostgreSQLでやる

ことを検討します。

Answer (score 0):

型等が不明ですが、仮にdateとintegerと仮定して、
最初の日はminで取得できます。
変化があった＝違う日のデータが入っていたとするならば

```
create table Test(observed_at date, reputation integer);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-1",1000);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-2",1000);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-3",1010);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-4",1010);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-5",1010);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-6",1045);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-7",1045);
insert into Test(observed_at, reputation) values("2017-11-8",1045);
```

maxとminをhavingで比較すればいいと思います。

```
select min(observed_at), reputation from Test group by reputation having  max(observed_at) != min(observed_at);
```

もし仮に同じ日付でデータが投入される可能性があり、それも変化があったとみなすのであれば
countして1より大きければというhaving比較すればいいと思います。

```
select min(observed_at), reputation from Test group by reputation having  count(observed_at) > 1 ;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ふと考えてみたところ、ある日プラスして、後の日にマイナスになって同じデータになった場合には、これですと正しく動いてくれないな、と思っている状態です。

Comment: 確かにマイナスになると駄目ですね。失礼しました。